# Install Ubuntu in a second drive and grub in the primary one

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I currently have 2 HD's:
120Gb SSD - Used by the existing Windows 7 OS
2Tb HDD - Here I have the user folder and all the programs.

I'm planning to install Ubuntu on my PC, but I would like to make a custom installation.

I would like to have 2 partitions on the SSD (for Windows and Ubuntu operating systems). Then I would like to have the /home folder on the HDD, so I'd like to have 2 partitions on the HDD too (for Windows and Ubuntu home dirs).

Is that possible? or is there a better setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a perfect solution!  (And kind of the way I run too, except for the Windows)

To actually do this, use the following steps:

1. [Back up everything!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) You've been promoted to User type 4 now!  **;-)**
2. Turn of fast boot/hybrid hibernation under Windows 7 (if set)
3. Boot from the Ubuntu Live DVD
4. Choose "Try Ubuntu"
5. run `gparted` and resize the Windows partition (SSD) and data partition
6. boot into Windows and let it finish its `chkdsk`
7. Boot again from the Ubuntu Live DVD
8. Install and create 2 partitions on the SSD and 2 on the HDD:

   1. `swap` partition of size using [this table](https://askubuntu.com/a/594402/344926)
   2. `ext4` partition for `/` minimum 16GB for Lubuntu, 24 for Xubuntu and 48 for Ubuntu, but more is better!
   3. `ext4` Partition for `/home` as much as you can afford
   4. FAT32 (4GB) just for exchanging data between Windows and Ubuntu

### Done!

P.S. If you like more complicated partitioning, [have a look here...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

Comment: Hi, i've never partitioned manually and I wouldn't lose data :/

Can you explain the partitioning procedure a bit more?
How can I set the /home dir in the hdd instead of the ssd?

Anyways, thanks for answering, i didn't know that it was possible.

Comment: The exact procedure on how to use manual partition during install is [explained here already](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).  So don't forget to accept this answer as a valid answer before you dash off reading the other answer!  **;-)**