# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu alongside my windows 7.But the Ubuntu installation still doesn't detect windows on the system. It gives me the options to erase all data on the hard drive or do something else, and if I do something else then I get a list of partitions.

“Install alongside” option missing.
What else can I do to get the installation to detect windows?

Thanks for any help :) !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from Ubuntu install media and  choose <kbd>Try Ubuntu without installing</kbd>.
2. Open the built-in tool `gparted` and you will find all partitions there.
3. If there is sufficient **unallocated space** on your disk select this space,
   after you have chosen <kbd>Something else</kbd> when starting the installation.
   If the whole disk is used by Windows installation reduce this partition.
4. Create a new partition and format it with `ext4` with a size that is fitting your needs.
   Create another new partition and format it with a `swap` size [according to these rules](https://askubuntu.com/a/594402/344926).
5. Start the installation and select the `ext4` partition for the Ubuntu (root) system.