# Ubuntu Studio 15.10 installer cannot recognize already installed and working Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

As a new Ubuntu (and new Linux) user I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a Dell Inspiron 5547.

I would like to install an Ubuntu Studio 15.10 alongside the existing "normal" Ubuntu to enjoy the low latency kernel for recording music. Unfortunately, the install indicates that "This computer currently has no detected operating systems", so I can make a clean install only.

**efibootmgr:**

```
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder 0003,2003,0000,2001,2002
Boot0000  Ubuntu
Boot0001* UEFI Onboard LAN IPv4
Boot0002* UEFI Onboard LAN IPv6
Boot0003* ubuntu
Boot0004* USB1-1 (General USB Flash Disk)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002  EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

the output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`:

```
sda; ;931.5G
|-sda1;vfat;512M
|-sda2;ext2;244M
|-sda3;LVM2_member;930.8G
......|-ubuntu--vg-root;ext4;922.9G
......|-ubuntu--vg-swap_1;swap;7.9G
sdb; ;28.9G
|-sdb1;vfat;28.9G;/cdrom
loop0;ext3;4G
loop1;squashfs;2.3G /rofs
```

**BIOS - Boot menu: UEFI BOOT:**

1. HDD1-ubuntu (ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB)
2. UEFI Onboard LAN IPv4
3. UEFI Onboard LAN IPv6
4. USB1-1 (General USB Flash Disk)

Option-1 starts Ubuntu 15.10 perfectly.
Oprion-4 starts Live USB, I select "Install...", connect to the WiFi and later on the <kbd>Installation Type</kbd> screen I can see `This computer currently has no detected operating systems...`

*Could you please help me to solve this issue?*

Any "brutal" solution is fine with me, I am ready to reinstall everything if needed. **:-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need, you have a few options:

1. You don't need to install Ubuntu Studio just to get a low-latency or real-time kernel: you can do that from your existing Ubuntu installation...

   Before you begin: read the [official documentation on real-time kernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel) but if you only need to record audio, no need for real-time kernel: a low-latency kernel is good enough:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
   ```
2. If you need all the bells and whistles of Ubuntu Studio: use the brute force method and install Ubuntu Studio over your existing install.

   <sub>Don't blame me: you *asked* for a brute force method. **;-)**</sub>
3. If you need both Ubuntu's, ***there is absolutely no reason to do this,*** but if that's what you want:

   Boot the Ubuntu Studio first, delete all partitions except your EFI partition and create the following partitions: `swap` [according to this formula](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1-128gb-ram-on-14-04) `/`: 100GB, and `/home`: 800GB.

   Then install Ubuntu, creating an additional `/` of 100GB and use the existing `swap` and `/home` from Ubuntu Studio as your Ubuntu "Normal" swap and home.

   **Note:** you will need to update both Ubuntu's regularly and install all applications on both systems.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Dera Fabby, thank you very much for the repairing my question!

Thank you very much for the answer as well! 
Actually I would like to separate the two environments (Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio) because I heard that Low Latency or Real Time kernels have slightly weaker performance for other purposes.

Anyway, in case the issue with this dual boot can be solved anyhow, that would be great! :)

Thank you very much again!

All the best,
István

Comment: @IstvánHorváth: Please don't thank me,!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the "1" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: Thank you!  Favour returned and you're a Rep 8 user already!

Comment: Thank You, you helped a lot! Once I will see someone else struggling with the similar issue, I will link your Answer! :) All the best, István

Comment: Szívesen! **;-)**