# Pros and cons of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, bootloader

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows on my laptop. I already know how to install it. A tutorial that I watched recommended selecting the *Something else* option of the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer rather than installing Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager.

[image: Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager]

I'm confused about what are the pros and cons of the *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager* option. I created a partition in my hard drive. I want to install Ubuntu in the other partition, but I want also to choose the *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager* option. Is this possible, and is it safe to choose that option?

Comment: The "Something else..." option has nothing to do with "windows boot manager".  Windows is booted by its own boot manager, and Ubuntu by its own, regardless of the option you choose.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On a personal note, I would recommend you to stick with the *"Something else"* option only. The reason is that I have personally created issues with 4 laptop hard disks simply because I failed to understand the right process.

Choosing *"Install alongside Windows boot manager"* is safe, but please do take note of everything to avoid creating issues with your hard disk. If you are in any doubt, stick with the *"Something else"* option only.

Refer to [dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) if you want to perform every step with utmost caution.

Once you are done installing Ubuntu, perform the following steps to setup your grub menu:

- Boot into Windows OS
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> together to open the "Run" dialog.
- Type `cmd` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to start the command prompt as Administrator.  Select "Yes" to the UAC "Do you want to allow ..." dialog.

  - Alternatively, right-click on the Start Menu and select *"Windows PowerShell (Admin)"* (under Windows 10) or *"Windows Terminal (Admin)"* (under Windows 11).
- Type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note: You do need to have Admin rights in the command prompt before you perform the above action.  If `bcdedit` fails, please make sure you are running the prompt as Admin.

Comment: sorry for follow up question.  I have 4gb ram. do I need swap space partition?

Comment: @user3818576 it's better to have one. It will not affect your working in any way. – mAnN 32 mins ago

Comment: @user3818576 [Swap answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-8tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher/594402#594402)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager* option in the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer is the way that the Ubuntu installer incorrectly identified Windows, because that is the way that the existing Windows OS is identified in the system's configuration.

> Is it safe to choose that option?

It's not always safe to choose that option. If there is already a Windows EFI system partition, the Ubuntu installer will often detect it and use the existing Windows system partition instead of creating a new one, but if the Ubuntu installer did not correctly identify the existing Windows OS it's possible that it also did not identify the partition that is used by the computer to boot Windows, if such a partition exists. In such a case it's possible that Ubuntu will not install the grub bootloader because it doesn't know where to install grub, and the entire Ubuntu installation will abort. If this happens you can still install Ubuntu by choosing the *Something else* option at the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer.

The EFI System Partition (ESP) is a partition on a data storage device (usually an HDD or SSD) that is used by computers adhering to the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI). The EFI System Partition is an interface that's used by the computer to boot Windows. It's like a step that is taken before it runs the Windows partition. It's a small  partition, but without that partition your computer wouldn't know how to boot Windows.

*The EFI system partition (ESP) is an OS-independent partition that acts as the storage place for the EFI bootloaders, applications and drivers to be launched by the UEFI firmware. It is mandatory for UEFI boot.*  <sup>[source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFI_system_partition)</sup>

The EFI System Partition is a dedicated partition on GPT. It's usually a small one (100-**500** MB) formatted as FAT (usually FAT32) located at the beginning of the disk, and its partition record is at the beginning of the GPT (GUID Partition Table).