# Main Drive is not showing in the Ubuntu Simple Install

Tags: system-installation, drive

My system has Windows installed on a 500GB Intel 660p SSD, and a 1TB HDD purely for storage, that is currently empty.

When installing Ubuntu off a flash drive, if I use the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" option under Installation type, the next screen only gives me the option to partition off some of the HDD. In the drop down menu for select drive, the HDD is the only option.

If I use the "Something Else" option, the SSD shows up, but this is a more complicated screen, where I have the option to select either entire drive or 1 of the 4 partitions, I'd rather figure out why the simple install can't be done on the main drive.

The SSD also shows up fine when browsing in Ubuntu (running it off the flash drive).

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager is a "dual boot" (two operating systems side-by-side).

If that's your goal, here's a link on askUbuntu [weighing the Pros & Cons of dual-booting w/Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009311/pros-and-cons-of-installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows-boot-manager).

If that's *not* your goal, and you're instead looking to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu that wipes everything else away and starts clean over the old system, then you'd select "erase disk and install Ubuntu".  This erases Windows and installs Ubuntu, and from there you can partition the operating system (Ubuntu) onto your SSD and keep your HDD available for data storage.

Comment: It was my goal, i hadn't realised that the Ubuntu installer wouldn't want to create its own partition (doubly confusing cause it seemed happy to do it on the HDD) but once I shrank the windows partition to leave unallocated space it installed happily enough. But thanks for the link, it was interesting reading, i've got a lot to figure out.