# How can I modify the boot loader string of an existing UEFI entry from linux?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, uefi, efibootmgr

How do you modify, e.g., the loader or label attributes of a UEFI boot entry from linux?

The man page suggests that the following should work (assuming I want to change bootnum entry 0008):

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -b 0008 -L "wanted-label"
$ sudo efibootmgr -b 0008 -l '\EFI\ubuntu\whatever.efi'
```

However, the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v` before and after the above commands produce identical output. I have tried it on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 systems with the same result.

Is it possible to change the above mentioned attributes of a UEFI boot entry from linux? If so, *how*?

Background: My original problem is that I have a Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04 dual-boot system and wish to modify the boot loader string of the Windows Boot Manager UEFI entry to keep Ubuntu as my default boot system. The answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009311/pros-and-cons-of-installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows-boot-manager) explains how to to the modification from **Windows**. I would like to do it from **linux**.

Comment: You can change order with efibootmgr and -o See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and `man efibootmgr` or create new entries and delete old or duplicate entries. More examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win & https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples

Comment: I think you have to delete and recreate the entry.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125920/how-can-i-change-the-names-of-items-in-the-efi-uefi-boot-menu