# How do I dual boot Kubuntu with an existing non-OEM install of Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

#### A bit of history on this computer:

I built this computer in 2015 back before Windows 10 was released. The BIOS accepts both UEFI and non-UEFI devices as bootable media and I turned off Fast Boot quite soon as I found it annoying. I had the option of getting either a Windows 7 or Windows 8 installation disk and opted for the Win 7 one because:

1. I already had a laptop that came pre-installed with Win 8 and didn't like its start menu garbage and
2. I had heard rumors that Win 8 was less secure than Win 7.

A couple of years later when Windows began to offer a free upgrade to Win 10, I decided to accept the offer and upgraded Windows.

#### Back to the present:

I have recently decided that I want to install Kubuntu 18.04 LTS in a dual boot configuration with my current install of Win 10. I have managed to shrink the C:\ partition of my drive to half its original size but I can't manually add the partitions necessary to follow other installation procedures that I have found as the unallocated region becomes "unusable" after I add a single partition during installation.

#### Requested Information:

**Output of `sudo parted --list`:**

```
Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00B (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      106MB   500GB   500GB  primary  ntfs
 3      1000GB  1000GB  472MB  primary  ntfs         diag


Model: TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB  primary  ntfs         boot


Model: SanDisk Cruzer Blade (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 8004MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8004MB  8003MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

**Output of `sudo mount`:**

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4034560k,nr_inodes=1008640,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=811152k,mode=755)
/dev/sdc1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/cow on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=//filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow/upper,workdir=/cow/work)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=26,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=15448)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/999 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=811148k,mode=700,uid=999,gid=999)
```

Comment: Most Windows 7 installs are BIOS/MBR. The default installer was BIOS only, but could be reconfigured for UEFI, but few did that. And then upgrade to Windows 10 would still be BIOS, if drive is MBR(msdos) as Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR. And MBR has the 4 primary partition limit. Post this: `sudo parted -l` from live installer's terminal to your question above to preserve formatting. see also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: @oldfred Beat you to it!  **;-)**  Husky: Answer posted, you can remove all comments now...

Comment: One more not necessarily related problem is that 3TB drive is partitioned with MBR(msdos) converting to 2TB or otherwise using some proprietary configuration not compatible with Linux. It should be gpt partitioned.  And if ever installing a system to that drive include an ESP for UEFI boot or a bios_grub for BIOS boot. I normally partition new drives with both, but now only use UEFI.

Comment: **Huskey:** Thanks for the acceptance!  Favour returned: question upvoted! Please listen to **@old_fred** because he's actually better than me!  **;-)** (Now going to sleep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Please back up before doing the partitioning using [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php)

You're in luck:

You have 3 primary partitions on your 1TB drive with an MS-DOS partition table (4 partitions being the maximum):

```
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      106MB   500GB   500GB  primary  ntfs
 3      1000GB  1000GB  472MB  primary  ntfs         diag
```

So what you have to to is to:

- create one *extended partition* on the free space between Partition 2 and 3 (*taking all that space*, nearly 400GB)
- create logical EXT4 partitions inside the extended partition:

  - as many and of the size you like
  - grub and Ubuntu don't care whether they are on a primary or logical partition, whereas Windows 7 did and as you've upgraded, that's how Windows 10 is still configured.

Comment: Before I press that scary button, could you please double check my configuration? I'm reserving sda7 for a shared partition but I have no idea if that will work. Pic: http://imgur.com/VHQkPB0

Comment: also [have a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-1tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher/594402#594402) for swap and **remove all comments to keep things tidy in here... ;-)**  @Husky2490